# Passing Page State to Layout in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Since Gatsby V2 was implemented, I started a project where I would like to my pages having their own state for whatever thing and pass the value to the layout component.
But at this moment I'm not able to get the state there. Only the children and location.

This is the page:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'


class WorkPage extends Component {

  state = {
    intro : `WORK ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae augue id mi lobortis aliquet vitae et sem. 
            In fermentum ante sed turpis auctor finibus. Etiam sit amet leo eu arcu euismod ornare id pulvinar mauris. 
            Ut sagittis et urna et efficitur. Morbi porttitor lobortis accumsan. Curabitur hendrerit consequat dignissim.`, 
  }

  render(){
    const { intro } = this.state;
    return (
        <Layout intro={intro}>
          <h1>Work Page</h1>
          <p>Work content</p>
        </Layout>
     )
  }
}

export default WorkPage
```

And this is the layout:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  state = {
    status: null
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

render(){
   const {location, children, intro} = this.props
    return(
      <div>
        <div>{intro}</div>
        <div>{children}</div>
      </div>
      )
    }

}

export default Layout
```

Of course, showing the page state like in the example above It's not what I'm looking for but It's only for explaining what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Did you try a `console.log()`? What (error) messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap page in layout and pass intro as a prop to layout.

```
Layout intro={this.state.intro} 

 your page

/Layout
```

and then in Layout use `{this .props.intro}` at that place.

Comment: I have tried this but I never could reach these props you mention here :/

Comment: Ok! I have just checked that it's working when I reload :/
thanks both!